# How to get in a variable the value of the selection of a Select/Drop Down Menu PHP or HTML

Tags: php, postgresql, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to connect 2 drop-downs so in the first I show a list of countries and based on the selection of the country I show a list of the cities for the country selected.

I have my index.php file which load all the countries correctly as seen in this image:

[image]

Code to load my countries

```
<select name="country" id="country">
    <?php
    $db = pg_connect("$db_host $db_name $db_username $db_password");
    $query = "SELECT country FROM countries";

    $result = pg_query($query);
    if (!$result) {
        echo "Problem with query " . $query . "<br/>";
        echo pg_last_error();
        exit();
    }

    printf ("<option value=Select>Select a Country</option>");
    while($myrow = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    printf ("<option value=$myrow[country]>$myrow[country]</option>");
 }
    ?>
</select>
```

Now I'm trying to do the same based on the selection from the previous "Select" but it is not working. The issue I'm having is getting the value selected in the country select because if I hard-type a value of a country like: $query = "SELECT city FROM cities where country = Albania"; then it works. Also I tried to print the value of the country selected: (echo $selectedCountry;) and it not printing anything so I'm guessing neither $selectedCountry = $_GET['country']; or  $selectedCountry = $_POST['country']; are getting the value of the country selected.

```
<select name="city" id="city">
    <?php
    $db = pg_connect("$db_host $db_name $db_username $db_password");

$selectedCountry = $_GET['country'];
    $selectedCountry = $_POST['country'];
    echo $selectedCountry;

    $query = "SELECT city FROM cities where country = ' $selectedCountry '";

    $result = pg_query($query);
    if (!$result) {
        echo "Problem with query " . $query . "<br/>";
        echo pg_last_error();
        exit();
    }
    printf ("<option value=Select>Select a City</option>");
    while($myrow = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    printf ("<option value=$myrow[city]>$myrow[city]</option>");
}
    ?>
</select>
```

Thank you very much in advance

**UPDATE**

This is what I see in the first Load. Where the country Select is loaded with all the values as per the image above and the city Select is empty (Only the "Select a city" value) waiting to be loaded with the values depending on the country selection.

[image]

**LAST UPDATE - From Borna Suggestion**

Borna,

I've tried your suggestion, below the exact code that I'm using. Using two countries as example. However, the cities are empty the first load and when I select a country nothing loads in the city Select and I get the following screen. It seams that it is actually not calling/running the getCities.php:

[image]

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script>
    function populateCities(citiesSelectBoxOptions){
        document.getElementById("city").innerHTML = citiesSelectBoxOptions;
    }

    function httpGetAsync(theUrl, callback)
    {
        alert(theUrl);
        var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200)
                callback(xmlHttp.responseText);
        }
        xmlHttp.open("GET", theUrl, true); // true for asynchronous
        xmlHttp.send(null);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>

<select name="country" id="country" onchange="httpGetAsync('http://localhost/FillCity/getCities?country=' + this.value, populateCities)">
<option value="Angola">Angola</option>
<option value="Spain">Spain</option>
</select>

<select name="city" id="city">

</select>

</body>
</html>
```

getCities.php

```
<?php

include("config.php");

$db = pg_connect("$db_host $db_name $db_username $db_password");
$selectedCountry = $_GET['country'];
echo "country: " .$country;

$query = "SELECT city FROM cities where country = ' $selectedCountry '";

$result = pg_query($query);
if (!$result) {
echo "Problem with query " . $query . "<br/>";
echo pg_last_error();
exit();
}
printf ("<option value='Select'>Select a City</option>");
while($myrow = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) {
printf ("<option value='$myrow[city]'>$myrow[city]</option>");
}
?>
```

**UPDATE**

If I run http://localhost/FillCity/getCities?country=Spain this is what I get

[image]

If I run just http://localhost/FillCity/getCities.php I get: (I'm getting the word country because I place and echo $country in the code to see the country selected)

[image]

This is my FillCity folder under my localhost (var/www/html)

[image]

And here is what I see when running the Index.html for the first time with Angola as default country.

[image]

If I select any country, Spain, as example this is what I get

[image]

**LAST UPDATE**

When I open the .html file and I select a country this is what I get (Still printing out that message on the screen):

[image]

Once I click Ok then it works and I can see all the cities for the country (But of course I would like not to have that message popping up)

[image]

Thanks again

Comment: When you first load index.php are both dropdowns already loaded? I mean, you said it populates the country list fine, but is it also building the city list at the same time, and displaying all cities, regardless of country, or what?

Comment: @P.Gearman It doesn't metter because he is using the value of $_GET['country']. My advice is that you try with native select box, and see if it works.

Comment: @Borna  What is native select box?  Thanks

Comment: Well, I was trying to understand if the second dropdown is loaded through an AJAX call or if it was there the whole time.

Comment: @P.Gearman  First load all countries are loaded as per the image attached. However, cities are not loaded. The city selector only has the : "Select city" value. Thanks

Comment: @P.Gearman  It is not loaded through an AJAX call. It is there the whole time but empty. The intention is to load the values of the cities once a country is selected. However, the Select is there. I have updated my original post to show how it looks the first time. Thanks

Comment: @SamueldelRio What I meant is, what do you use to design the select box this way? Do you use anything besides html and css? e.g. jQuery

Comment: @Borna  No, I just use HTML and CSS and well PHP to gather the data from my postgresql DDBB. Really it works perfect for the country and it actually works for the city. The issue I'm having is to be able to store the value selected in the country dropbox to use it on my SQL to feed the city dropbox.  Something like $selectedCountry = $_GET['country'];  or $selectedCountry = country.selected; or anything of that nature to store the value selected in my dropbox. Thanks again

Comment: When you submit your form, the selected value is automaticaly set into $_GET["country"] or $_POST["country"] , depends on your method (GET or POST), so that part is fine. Try fixing the html by puting quotes around attribute value. "<option value='$myrow[city]'>$myrow[city]</option>"

Comment: @Borna  I need to get the value of the country before I click submit. Once I click submit all the values are sent to my DDBB and cannot make a selection of the city. I also tried with $selectedCountry = $_REQUEST['country']; but it is not working either. I saw that with javascript would be something like $selectedCountry = $("#country").is("selected").text();  but don't know how to include Javascript within PHP. Maybe I need Javascrip and I cannot store the selection of a country in a variable untill I click submit (which doesn't solve my issue) Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, what you really need is AJAX call which allows you to communicate with server without reloading a page. All you have to do is basically send a new HTTP request with a country parameter to get the list of cities in it. The correct way would be to send (HTTP response) only the data(cities) in JSON or similar format, and not its presentation also (html), but for simplicity, you can continue to work like you started (return data with html).

Start by separating the code that generates HTML selectBoxOptions of cities in another script.
You will use that script to get the list of cities in particular country by using AJAX (XMLHttpRequest library).

Have a look at this, it's a working solution of your problem. HTTP request is sent whenever user changes the countrySelectBox option, that way your cities select box gets updated every time it needs.
All you have to do is change the url in the onchange attribute that points to your script (I previously said that you should move 2nd block of code into separate script).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <script>
        function populateCities(citiesSelectBoxOptions){
            document.getElementById("city").innerHTML = citiesSelectBoxOptions;
        }

        function httpGetAsync(theUrl, callback)
        {
            alert(theUrl);
            var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200)
                    callback(xmlHttp.responseText);
            }
            xmlHttp.open("GET", theUrl, true); // true for asynchronous
            xmlHttp.send(null);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>


<select name="country" id="country" onchange="httpGetAsync('www.yourdomain.com/getCities.php?country=' + this.options[this.selectedIndex].value, populateCities)">
    <option value="Country1">Country 1</option>
    <option value="Country2">Country 2</option>
</select>

<select name="city" id="city">

</select>

</body>
</html>
```

getCities.php

```
<?php

$db = pg_connect("$db_host $db_name $db_username $db_password");

$selectedCountry = $_GET['country'];

$query = "SELECT city FROM cities where country = ' $selectedCountry '";

$result = pg_query($query);
if (!$result) {
    echo "Problem with query " . $query . "<br/>";
    echo pg_last_error();
    exit();
}
printf ("<option value='Select'>Select a City</option>");
while($myrow = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    printf ("<option value='$myrow[city]'>$myrow[city]</option>");
}
?>
```

EDIT:

httpGetAsync is native (only pure/vanilla javascript is used. No other libraries are used) javascript function that enables you to send HTTP request without reloading a page. I see you are using jQuery, which hides this function's complexity, same as form->submit, but I recommend you to learn how httpGetAsync works, because using a jQuery for such a simple task is overkill.

You don't need this javascript function

```
function getCity(countryId)
```

Instead, you should put your code that communicates with database in a .php file, not in javascript (remember, javascript is a client side, it executes on client machine, e.g. browser, while php executes on server). Your SQL should never be written in javascript. Client side code cannot communicate with a database directly, only through server side coding. To accomplish that, you must return a value of PHP script getCities.php back to the client(javascript) as a HTTP response.

When you send a HTTP request to some .php file, that scripts executes on a server, and everything that you said "echo" or "print", on the end of script, is automaticaly sent as HTTP response. You don't actualy have to write any code to send a HTTP response. Its done automaticaly. You just have to echo/print whatever you need on the client side. In your case, you need to print options for particular country.

How the script knows for which country it needs to select cities from database?
Well, you send HTTP request with a parameter "country". That is what you Form is doing automaticaly when you submit it. All HTML tags that are inside Form, and have a name attribute set, are gonna be send in HTTP request as parameters. But, since you cannot use submit, you must do this manualy.

To send a parameter inside HTTP GET request is very simple.
Have a look at the following url:

```
localhost/getCities?country=countryX&someOtherParam=something&myThirdParam=something3
```

On server side, the following variables are gonna be populated:

```
$_GET["country"] // value is 'countryX'
$_GET["someOtherParam"] // value is 'something'
$_GET["myThirdParam"] // value is 'something3'
```

To learn more about how GET and POST works, and what is the difference, check [this](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp)

Get started by creating a getCities.php file, and copy paste the code that communicates with database and generates city options. It's basically what you already did, you just have to put that code in separate .php file. So, when a client (browser) asks for a list of cities in particular country, you are going to send a HTTP request (using httpGetAsync() function) to get that list from the server.

In your index.php copy paste this script

```
<script>
    function populateCities(citiesSelectBoxOptions){
        document.getElementById("city").innerHTML = citiesSelectBoxOptions;
    }

    function httpGetAsync(theUrl, callback)
    {
        alert(theUrl);
        var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200)
                callback(xmlHttp.responseText);
        }
        xmlHttp.open("GET", theUrl, true); // true for asynchronous
        xmlHttp.send(null);
    }
</script>
```

Next, put onchange attribute on select box, remember, its all lower case, not onChange.

```
<select name="country" id="country" onchange="httpGetAsync('localhost/getCities?country=' + this.value, populateCities)">
```

For any question just ask... :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I tried with your code and cannot make it work. I guess because my programming knowledge is a little limited and cannot follow all the instructions as for example I don't konw what httpGetAsync does. However, I restarted with a different option where I'm very close to my result and which I posted as Update. Thanks again

Comment: I feel embarrass to ask but I'm using the code provided and still not working. Please see the last update I posted on the original post where I included a printshoot of the issue I'm having. I also posted all the code as I'm using it. Thank you so much again. I really appreciate your help

Comment: @SamueldelRio Why do you have HTML in getCities.php? It should be in your index.html

Comment: I don't know what I was doing when pasting the code but I didn't have the HTML code in my php file but in the index.html. I've fixed in the original post to reflect my code. The issue is still the same. Thanks again

Comment: Have you tryed running url in browser directly? http://localhost/FillCity/getCities?country=Spain. Go to this location via browser and check if it outputs html options.

Comment: The thing is that you should test component by component, its much easyer to find bug.

Comment: And btw, you really should not echo the error message, because if error happens, the error will be send to the client and be written into your DOM document (HTML select). The cities should be either sent, or not (empty response body). To distinguish whether or not the response is valid, is by using HTTP status code. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Comment: I updated my original post with what I get by running localhost/FillCity/getCities?country=Spain and also other screen that might be helpful of what I see and what I get. Thank you so much again

Comment: @SamueldelRio The problem is with request url. This link http://localhost/FillCity/getCities?country=Spain   The problem is that you forgot .php extension... the actual file is named getCities.php. By entering only getCIties?... you made a request to the file called getCities, and since your server didn't find a file with that name, it returned "Not found error".

Comment: I updated the original post. Actually in that case I get the same as if I just call getCities.php. Actually I get the same result for whatever country I put after country=.  Thanks again

Comment: I tried that and I posted a printshoot of the result. I still don't be able to retrieve the cities. Actually doesn't retrieve the select. The last update with last printshoot reflects the result of call http://localhost/FillCity/getCities.php?country=Spain

Comment: Your where query seems wrong, you must not put extra space at each side, unless its really how its written in your database. Script didn't return error because there is no one. The query couldnt find match, so it returned 0 rows...  So... change ' $selectedCountry ' to:  '$selectedCountry'

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!! that was the issue why I didn't retrieved cities for the selected country.  However, If I open the index.html file I still get the same issue. Please see Last Update on Original Post. Thanks

Comment: @SamueldelRio The problem is ones again with missing .php extension inside your onchange javascript method. You should be careful with copy/paste; it usually speeds up the process, but many times it will be your nightmare :D

Comment: THANK YOU, THANK YOU. It works now. I promise that this is the last one. So even it works, it does still print out the message before where I have to click ok before to see the cities. See last Update on original message. THANKS!!!!!!!!

Comment: hmm, don't understand what you wanna say, can you put update at the end of your post?

Comment: Did you mean the alert message? Can't you just delete it? It's written somewhere in your javascript

Comment: function httpGetAsync(theUrl, callback)
    {
        alert(theUrl);

Answer (score 1):

Well, I suppose one way to do it would be with jQuery.

There's probably a few different ways to do this, but what you could do, is load all the cities into the city drop-down, regardless of country, but change the `printf` for the city options like this.

```
$query = "SELECT city, country FROM cities";
....
while($myrow = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    printf ("<option class="$myrow[country] city_select" value=$myrow[city]>$myrow[city]</option>");
}
```

And then in the javascript for the page, have something like

```
$('#country').bind('change', function(){
    var country = $(this).val();
    $('#city option.city_select').hide();
    $('#city option.'+country+'').show();
});
```

It's not necessarily the most elegant solution, though.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the quotes inside your option, it should be something like

```
<option value=$myrow['city']>$myrow['city']</option>
```

try that

Comment: Thank you but don't need quotes in there. Actually for the country works without the quotes. Thanks

Comment: yeah i just relised that haha sorry