# How would you design this webpage with multiple forms?

Tags: javascript, php

I currently have a simple php/html page with only one form, where the user inputs a number, then the page loads itself (but this time with parameters).

Some key codelines :

```
<form action="index.php" method="get">
  <input type="text" name="name">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>


<?php
  if (!isset ($_GET["name"])) { 

    echo "<div> Adding some content related to the input </div>";
  } 
?>
```

Now i'm looking forward adding 3 more fields, and split my page for each form. 
The user should be free to use the 4 forms separately, I don't want to have the page reload every time. I'm unsure how to design this page - should i rework my page and work with JS ?

I have basic knowledge with PHP, a little with JS. I will be able to google up most things i need but first i need a proper direction :) thanks !

Comment: So you want the page to load only when the user click on 'submit' ?

Comment: *The user should be free to use the 4 forms separately* - what exactly do you mean by that? Submit each form independently? Why? Do they need different validation or to post to different responses? Why not 1 form with 4 fieldsets (or sections)? I'm not entirely clear on what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: @TimB Yes but there will be 4 Submit buttons

Comment: @CD001 each time the user clicks Submit, it performs many requests and processing, it takes a while, so with 4 forms the user might want to just use the first form, wait for a while, then move onto the second form while still being able to look at the first form, and without having my page to peform again the work related to other forms

Comment: Are the forms depending on each other?

Comment: If you want 4 forms should be work independently.. Then basic idea is to create a page with 4 frame and each frame will contains it's on form. In this way, when any form is submitted then only that frame will be reloaded.

Comment: @Borna no. It's like if each form would display every possible anagram with the name entered. The user will try with one name, have the result displayed, and then try with another name on the second form without changing the content of the first form, etc.

Comment: All you need is ajax (javascript library XMLHttpRequest). Check my earlyer post describing a similar problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37194895/how-to-get-in-a-variable-the-value-of-the-selection-of-a-select-drop-down-menu-p/37196909#37196909

Comment: Thanks everyone, i've already got a load of stuff to consider/read from your comments

Comment: I recommend you to learn how to use native XMlHttpRequest library, instead of using the jQuery's ajax implementation (it actually uses the native library under the hood)

Comment: Actually JQuery uses the relevant XMLHttpRequest implementation for the browser in question (i.e. older versions of IE use an ActiveX control); `JQuery.ajax()` irons out those differences and gives you a single interface - tbh it's the main reason I started using JQuery over native JS. @Borna

Answer (score 0):

you can use AJAX for this purpose...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

// process the form
$('form').submit(function(event) {

    // get the form data
    // there are many ways to get this data using jQuery (you can use the class or id also)
    var formData = {
        'name'              : $('input[name=name]').val(),
        'email'             : $('input[name=email]').val(),
    };

    // process the form
    $.ajax({
        type        : 'POST', // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (POST for our form)
        url         : 'process.php', // the url where we want to POST
        data        : formData, // our data object
        dataType    : 'json', // what type of data do we expect back from the server
        encode      : true
    })
        // using the done promise callback
        .done(function(data) {

            // log data to the console so we can see
            console.log(data); 

            // here we will handle errors and validation messages
        });

    // stop the form from submitting the normal way and refreshing the page
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

});

Comment: I just took a look at what AJAX is, i suppose that's what i'll have to focus on, thanks

Answer (score 0):

AJAX is a must if you don't want the page to reload between each interaction.

If you have trouble with it and want to opt for just PHP (with page reloads) you can handle multiple forms on one page easily enough - my preferred method is to set a hidden value in the form called 'action' settings its value & reading this in again when the page loads for example:

```
 <?php if(isset($_POST['action']))
{
    $action = $_POST['action'];


    switch ($action)
    {
        case 'hello':

                echo 'hello';

        break;  



        case 'bye':

                echo 'bye';

        break;  


    }

}

?>


<form method="post" action="Untitled-5.php">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="hello"/>
<input type="submit" value="hello"/>

</form>



<form method="post" action="Untitled-5.php">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="bye"/>
<input type="submit" value="bye"/>

</form>
```

You could then save and echo out the values for each form each time keeping them updated as the user interacts with each of the forms.

AJAX is the nicer solution however

Answer (score -1):

If you do not want to reload the page every time you submit each form then you should use Ajax for calling your api. You write the separate api in PHP, and then call that api in Jquery's Ajax.

Here the page won't be reloaded. Also you can call the ajax on each of the button click.